# Páginas HTML com leitura/escrita variáveis

Tags: html, algoritmo, arduino

Preciso de apoio neste projeto de embarcados, utilizando ESP32 e IDE arduino.
A dificuldade seria em exibir e ler VARIAVEIS na pagina HTML pois encontrei somente esses exemplos:

- [Referência em português - Chamar de code A](https://capsistema.com.br/index.php/2020/02/02/servidor-da-web-esp32-dht11-dht22-temperatura-e-umidade-usando-o-arduino-ide/)
- [Referência em Inglês- Chamar de code B](https://www.john-lassen.de/en/projects/easy-webpage-handling-on-esp2)

Estou codificado no code B (está funcionando certinho) e preciso mesclar com o code A.

No arquivo "ESP_Web_Namespace_Example.ino", tenho seguinte código:

```
#ifndef _WPAGE_
#define _WPAGE_

#include <WebServer.h>
#include <Update.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
//#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

#include "pagehelper.h"
#include "index.html.h"
#include "settings.html.h"
#include "style.css.h"
#include "smiley.jpg.h"
#include "wifi.html.h"
#include "server.html.h"
#include "display.html.h"
#include "gerais.html.h"
#include "logo.jpg.h"

WebServer Wbit(80);

String readDHTTemperature() {
  // As leituras do sensor também podem ter até 2 segundos 'de idade (é um sensor muito lento)
  // Leia a temperatura como Celsius (o padrão)
  float t = random(0,1000);
  // Leia a temperatura como Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  //float t = dht.readTemperature(true);
  // Verifique se alguma leitura falhou e saia mais cedo (para tentar novamente).
  if (isnan(t)) { 
    Serial.println("Falha ao ler do sensor DHT!");
    return "--";
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(t);
    return String(t);
  }
}

String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == "MSG1"){
    return readDHTTemperature();
  }
  else if(var == "MSG2"){
    //return readDHTHumidity();
  }
  return String();
}



void web2(){


  // CSS
    Wbit.on(style_css::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/css", style_css::estilo); });

    // HTML - PAGES
    Wbit.on("/", [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html::HtmlPage); });  // Startpage
    
    Wbit.on(settings_html::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", settings_html::HtmlPage); });  // Settings

    Wbit.on(index_html::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html::HtmlPage); });  // index

     // wifi

    Wbit.on(wifi_html::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", wifi_html::HtmlPage); });

     // servidor
    Wbit.on(server_html::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", server_html::HtmlPage); });

 // display
    Wbit.on(display_html::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", display_html::HtmlPage); });

     // gerais
    Wbit.on(gerais_html::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", gerais_html::HtmlPage); });

    // IMAGES
    Wbit.on(smiley_jpg::PageName(), [] {Wbit.sendContent_P(smiley_jpg::Image, sizeof(smiley_jpg::Image)); });

    // LOGOTIPO
    Wbit.on(logo_jpg::PageName(), [] {Wbit.sendContent_P(logo_jpg::Image, sizeof(logo_jpg::Image)); });

    Wbit.begin();
  
}

void webloop2(){
  Wbit.handleClient();
}

#endif
```

Como possível verificar contém o trecho do code A:

```
String readDHTTemperature() {
  // As leituras do sensor também podem ter até 2 segundos 'de idade (é um sensor muito lento)
  // Leia a temperatura como Celsius (o padrão)
  float t = random(0,1000);
  // Leia a temperatura como Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  //float t = dht.readTemperature(true);
  // Verifique se alguma leitura falhou e saia mais cedo (para tentar novamente).
  if (isnan(t)) { 
    Serial.println("Falha ao ler do sensor DHT!");
    return "--";
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(t);
    return String(t);
  }
}
//Efetua a identificação das variáveis 
String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == "MSG1"){  //Busca no HTML a variavel %MSG1%
    return readDHTTemperature();
  }
  else if(var == "MSG2"){ //Busca no HTML a variável %MSG2%
    //return readDHTHumidity();
  }
  return String();
}
```

O ponto critico é code A, que possui:

- `server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){  request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);`

E code B, a linha respectiva seria essa abaixo:

- `Wbit.on("/", [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html::HtmlPage); });  // Startpage`

Por fim, a tentativa modificar, gera erro, para código que adiciona chamada a processor (processor faz a identificação/modificação das variáveis no corpo HTML)

`Wbit.on("/", [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html::HtmlPage,processor); });  // Startpage`

Creio que necessário compreender a sintaxe do comando acima.

O arquivo index.html contém (mostrando somente o trecho que mostra as variáveis):

```
<h3>MENSAGENS DO DISPLAY</h3>
              <div class="conteudo">
                <div> 
                  <span>MENSAGEM DA LINHA 1</span>
                  <input type="text" maxlength="16" value="%MSG1%">
                </div>
                
                <div> 
                  <span>MENSAGEM DA LINHA 2</span>
                  <input type="text" maxlength="16" value="%MSG2%">
                </div>
           </div>
```

Entretanto, caso não seja possível uma solução, preciso de mais referências de exemplo desta integração/portabilidade. Necessito, compreender e saber o que estudar, para não depender de fonte de terceiros.

Comment: Qual o erro retorna?

Comment: sketch\web_pages.cpp: In lambda function:

web_pages.cpp:75:101: error: invalid conversion from 'String (*)(const String&)' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]

     Wbit.on(index_html::PageName(), [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", index_html::HtmlPage,processor); });  // index

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, a biblioteca usa o sinal de `%` na variável no HTML, como em um template, talvez a função espere um formato numérico e está recebendo string

Comment: https://links2004.github.io/Arduino/d3/d58/class_e_s_p8266_web_server.html
Wbit.on("/", HTTP_GET, [] {Wbit.send_P(200, "text/html", display_html::HtmlPage,int(processor)); });  // CORRETO De acordo com a referência acima, é esperado um inteiro. Código compilou sem erros, porém não obtive sucesso no objetivo final, tenho que estudar como faz a troca de informação. Obrigado a todos